# Efficient way(No in-memory read) of extracting a huge csv log file in reusable code without using pandas?

Tags: python

I have this csv log file which is huge in size (GBs)and has no header row:

```
1,<timestamp>,BEGIN
1,<timestamp>,fetched from db
1,<timestamp>,some processing
2,<timestamp>,BEGIN
2,<timestamp>,fetched from db
1,<timestamp>,returned success
3,<timestamp>,BEGIN
4,<timestamp>,BEGIN
1,<timestamp>,END
3,<timestamp>,some work
2,<timestamp>,some processing
4,<timestamp>,waiting for
2,<timestamp>,ERROR
3,<timestamp>,attempting other work
4,<timestamp>,ERROR
3,<timestamp>,attempting other work
```

Each line is a trace-log, and the first field is the `RequestID`.
Need to scan the file and store the logs only for requests which resulted in `'ERROR'` to another file.

```
import csv
def readFile(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fn:
        reader = csv.reader(fn)
        for line in reversed(list(reader)):
            yield (line)

def wrt2File():
    rows = readFile('log.csv')
    with open('error.csv', 'w') as fn:
        writer = csv.writer(fn)
        errReqIds = []
        for row in rows:
            if 'ERROR' in row:
                errReqIds.append(row[0])
            if row[0] in errReqIds:
                writer.writerow(row)

wrt2File()
```

How to improve my code not to use memory for **readFile** operation and re-usability of this code? I don't want to use pandas, if any better alternative is available.

Comment: why: `for line in reversed(list(reader))`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga AFAICT the "ERROR" message marker happens at the end of the request obviously, so the OP used `reversed` to first get the request_id marker then collect the logs for this request_id.

Comment: What is the delimiter character in the `log.csv` file? Is it the tab (`'\t'`) character? It would be better if you put in an example of the real input data.

Comment: Why are you doing a `line.split()` when you're using a csv reader ? Is your log file REALLY a csv format ?

Comment: Also, the first obvious optimisation is to make `errReqIds` a set - set lookups are O(1) and much faster than list lookups.

Comment: Your code is reading in the entire `log.csv` file into memory. While relatively fast in terms of I/O, it uses a lot of RAM. Is that acceptable? What exactly are is—what do you consider "efficient" (and reusable)?

Comment: @martineau you are correct. the sample data was copied from a csv file and tried in txt format in console, same was copied to log.csv. The "line.split()" should not be there for original csv file processing.

Comment: I had updated the code for csv format consideration. By efficient, I mean no in-memory read.

Comment: @martineau could you point me in my code the **in-memory** read, which is exactly I want to avoid. What could be the best way of doing it? I thought using **yield** avoiding the in-memory read.

Comment: It's all read in when `list(reader)` executes in your `readFile()` function. **Not** reading them all into memory at once would slow things down considerably because of the need to sort the rows to group them together (so _all_ those associated with a given request id are written to the error csv).

Answer (score 1):

This does not look like CSV at all.  Might I suggest something along the following lines:

```
def extract(filename):
    previous = dict()
    current = set()
    with open(filename) as inputfile:
        for line in inputfile:
            id, rest = line.split(' ')
            if 'ERROR' in line:
                if id in previous:
                    for kept in previous[id]:
                        yield(kept)
                    del previous[id]
                yield(line)
                current.add(id)
            elif id in current:
                yield(line)
    # Maybe do something here to remove really old entries from previous

def main():
    import sys
    for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
        for line in extract(filename):
            print(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This simply prints to standard output. You could refactor it to accept an output file name as an option and use `write` on that filehandle if you like.

Comment: If indeed `ERROR` is always the last line in a set, you could improve this to use less memory and also be a bit simpler.

Comment: could you please explain "last line in set" since ERROR could be in any line

Comment: Then this should work, there was a comment on the question implying that the last line for a particular `id` will be the ERROR but I guess that's incorrect then.

Comment: ok  got it. It is true that "ERROR" for a particular "id" is always the last line. Then how do you improve to use less memory? Also, could you please explain my code, if entirely in-memory read happening?

Comment: Yes, the `list(reader)` in your attempt forces the CSV `reader` to fetch all the lines into memory, and then sit on them while you `yield` them one by one.

Comment: The `current` set can be dropped from this code but it's not a very significant change performance-wise. The big cost comes from keeping all the `id` items in memory for the entire file so far. If you can postulate an expiration policy for the `previous` dict (say, we can forget an `id` if it's more than X seconds ago or Y lines since we last saw it) you can keep the memory requirements down.

Answer (score 0):

Since your file is huge, you could need a solution which avoid to load the entire file in memory. The following can do this job:

```
def find_errors(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return {l[0:3] for l in f if 'ERROR' in l}

def wrt2File():
    error_ids = find_errors('log.csv')
    with open('error.csv', 'w') as fw, open('log.csv') as fr:
        [fw.write(l) for l in fr if l[0:3] in error_ids]
```

Note that I assumed the id was the first 3 characters of the line, change it if needed.

Comment: This is pretty nice, but requires two passes through the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that should be fairly fast, probably because it reads the entire file into memory to process it. You haven't defined what you mean by "efficent", so I assumed it was speed and that your computer has enough memory to do it—since that's what the code in your question does.

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter


REQUEST_ID = 0  # Column
RESULT = 2  # Column
ERROR_RESULT = 'ERROR'
keyfunc = itemgetter(REQUEST_ID)

def wrt2File(inp_filename, out_filename):

    # Read log data into memory and sort by request id column.
    with open(inp_filename, 'r', newline='') as inp:
        rows = list(csv.reader(inp))
        rows.sort(key=keyfunc)

    with open(out_filename, 'w', newline='') as outp:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(outp)
        for k, g in groupby(rows, key=keyfunc):
            g = list(g)
            # If any of the lines in group have error indicator, write
            # them to error csv.
            has_error = False
            for row in g:
                if row[RESULT] == ERROR_RESULT:
                    has_error = True
                    break
            if has_error:
                csv_writer.writerows(g)

wrt2File('log.csv', 'error.csv')
```

**Update:**

Since I now know you don't want read it all into memory, here's one alternative. It reads the entire file twice. The first time is just determine which request ids had errors in the lines logging them. This information is used the second time to determine which line to write to the errors csv. Your OS should do a certain amount of file buffering / and data cache, so hopefully it will be an acceptable trade-off.

*It's important to note that row for request ids with errors in the output file won't be grouped together since this approach doesn't sort them.*

```
import csv


REQUEST_ID = 0  # Column
RESULT = 2  # Column
ERROR_RESULT = 'ERROR'

def wrt2File(inp_filename, out_filename):

    # First pass:
    #   Read entire log file and determine which request id had errors.
    error_requests = set()  # Used to filter rows in second pass.
    with open(inp_filename, 'r', newline='') as inp:
        for row in csv.reader(inp):
            if row[RESULT] == ERROR_RESULT:
                error_requests.add(row[REQUEST_ID])

    # Second pass:
    #   Read log file again and write rows associated with request ids
    #   which had errors to the output csv
    with open(inp_filename, 'r', newline='') as inp:
        with open(out_filename, 'w', newline='') as outp:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(outp)
            for row in csv.reader(inp)
                if row[RESULT] in error_requests:
                    csv_writer.writerow(row)


wrt2File('log.csv', 'error.csv')
print('done')
```

Comment: by efficient, I meant for avoiding completely in-memory read. I should not use that. So is there any alternative?

Comment: @martneau I edited the question by defining what I meant for efficiency. Could you kindly optimized it avoiding in-memory read?